# Serviio throwing 553 on resource

Tags: html

I have the following setup:

1 serviio service running v1.2 on a server and when i fetch my streaming urls via an API, they work like they should
but now I want to upgrade it to v1.5.1, so I installed it on my dev computer, and when i fetch the list it gives me them

but then when I want to stream I get errorCode 553 (missing or invalid token)
but when I use the same token that I used to get all the videos, it has no problem.

I'm using the same code for fetching on v1.2 and then the tokens were valid.

any clue why this is happening?

this is the url I was using that throws the 553:
`http://localhost:23424/cds/resource/4/MEDIA_ITEM/AVC_MP4_MP_HD_720p_AAC-0/ORIGINAL?profile=html5?authToken=5e213da362d64b1c908d6be06b84720d`

this is the url I was using that works just fine:
`http://localhost:23424/cds/browse/html5/V_F%5EFOL_R1/BrowseDirectChildren/items/0/99999999?authToken=5e213da362d64b1c908d6be06b84720d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link should be:

```
http://localhost:23424/cds/resource/4/MEDIA_ITEM/AVC_MP4_MP_HD_720p_AAC-0/ORIGINAL?profile=html5&authToken=5e213da362d64b1c908d6be06b84720d
```

Note the `?` is converted to `&` to add the `authToken` back to query string.